# How to delete facebook post programmatically that has not been posted by your application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-post, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

How to delete Facebook post that is not posted by your application?

1. Using graph API - according to docs

/* make the API call */
`new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{post-id}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.DELETE,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    } ).executeAsync();`

Above code is not working.

It is giving error:-

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) This post wasn't created by the application",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
  }
}
```

2. Or does there exist some other method?

Comment: Under what conditions your app _can_ delete posts, is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post#deleting

Comment: There is an app (Xpire) which is able to delete fb post which it hasn't even posted. Link:- 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xpire-mass-delete-your-tweets-and-facebook-posts/id782634899?mt=8

Comment: Well then they are probably not using the API …

Comment: Can you tell what might be used by them in this case?

Comment: They are likely imitating the requests the official Facebook frontend/UI would be making to delete a post.

Comment: Hi. I am getting this issue in the delete schedule post. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64643614/6676310

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post):

> An app can delete any post it published, or a page-management app can delete a Post published to a Page that the app manages.

So it depends on what you are doing.

Comment: There is an app (Xpire) which is able to delete fb post which it hasn't even posted. Link:- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xpire-mass-delete-your-tweets-and-facebook-posts/id782634899?mt=8

Comment: Perhaps they don't use the API and work on the Facebook website instead. But without reverse engineering I can only poke around in the dark.

Comment: @Norbert I am getting this issue on delete schedule post. plz, let me know if you have any solution. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64643614/6676310